# dmidecode show 6 * 8GB DIMM but free -m only show 16GB?

Tags: centos6

I have CentOS 6.4 running on the top of HP ProLiant BL460c G7 blade server. I have 6 * 8GB DIMM memory installed on HP blade server.

When i use dmidecode --type memory, i get the following output

```
Handle 0x1000, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 192 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 6

Handle 0x1001, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 192 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 6

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 1D
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 2A
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x1102, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 3
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 3E
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1103, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 4
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 4B
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x1104, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 5
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 5F
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1105, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 6
    Locator: PROC 1 DIMM 6C
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x1106, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 7
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 1D
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1107, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 8
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 2A
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x1108, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 9
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 3E
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x1109, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 10
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 4B
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz

Handle 0x110A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 11
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 5F
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x110B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1001
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 12
    Locator: PROC 2 DIMM 6C
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1333 MHz
```

but when i type free -m, its just showing 16GB. I don't understand what is the issue here. Please help.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15914       4697      11216          0        226       3385
-/+ buffers/cache:       1085      14828
Swap:        18095         52      18043
```

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit system?

Comment: it is 32bit (i686)

Comment: Nice, that's an easy fix. You *must* use a 64 bit system to address that much memory.

Comment: Could you please send me some link that describes this ?

Comment: https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use a 64-bit system to address that much primary memory. The fact that you're able to address anything beyond ~4G is thanks to PAE, which is a way of logically extending the memory map for 32 bit systems. It doesn't scale very far, as you can see.

So reinstall with an amd64 distribution, and you will be able to address the rest of your memory.